# Is it possible to access connection string which defined in a C# class using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

I need to use entity framework in a application and I need to set username and password in connection string within web.config file from user inputs.Now I need to know how I can access to connection string where placed in web.config from a C# class that I define to reads inputs and set them in connection string?
Can I define a connection string within a C# class and entity framework use it?

Comment: The EF Context class constructor may receive an string with the connection string.

Comment: I think the question is how to pass a class to the constructor :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this code, but I think it's pretty close to the solution:

```
public static class ConnectionStrings
{
    public const string MyConnectionStrinGoesHere = "My connection string goes here";
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
}

public class ConnectionStringFromClassContext : Context
{
    public ConnectionStringFromClassContext() : base(ConnectionStrings.MyConnectionStrinGoesHere)
    {

    }
}
```

In your program you can than use:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConnectionStringFromClassContext context = new ConnectionStringFromClassContext();
}
```

And you'll pass the connectionstring defined in the static class.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but Now how I can set this ConnectionStringFromClassContext instance to web.config? How EF could access this connection string? Is it not required to define connection string in web.config with this approach?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want because it is not very clear.

Comment: When I config my connection string in my program I need to set that as a default connection string for Entity framework in web.config file. When I use EF it declare a connection string in web.config and use it to connect to the database.

Comment: If I use your solution could Entity Framework determines this the connection string which i declared programmatically?

Comment: Should be. EF uses name or full connection Stein gin constructor. My code creates a new context specifying the connection string. Give it a try

Comment: Hey. Just to see if my answer was sufficient and working. If not. Don't hesitate to ask.